# AIR on Android || playing large flv files from Application directory

Tags: android, air, adobe, flv

I am including a large flv file in an AIR project for Android.

I succeed in installing the application on the sd card (with Astro file browser)
Now when I play an flv file (residing in the application directory) of 5mb everything works just fine. When I use a larger flv file (300mb) nothing happens...

When putting the files on the sd card directly it does work, but I want to avoid this because my files are exposed like this. I tried en/decrypting of the flv file but that is painfully slow...

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Accordind to me use Darwin Streaming Server this is the properly worked on my machine

See link for more info

http://justdevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/10/video-streaming-with-android-phone.html#Video_Streaming_with_the_Google_Phone

Answer (score 0):

I believe the AIR framework is ok for easy/fast/standard usage of Android but from reading all the questions coming in SOF, I'd say its not suited for larger/weird/advanced app.

You might need to try the real Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for anwsers guys.

It seems that AIR is not the problem here actually. 
The problem is that when you install an application on the SD card and you write files into your bundle these files are not stored into the bundle on the SD card but they are written onto internal memory.

So pointing to your application directory when your app is on the SD card is actually pointing to internal memory storage on the device. This does not make any sense...

Which leaves me to writing files into 'user directory's' pointing to the SD card, but doing so leaves my files unprotected on the sd card. There are ways to do encryption/decryption but for larger files they slow down the process too much thus ruining the user experience.

It's like a multi headed dragon...Once you succeed in cutting one head of it grows even more... For each solution you find, you get an extra two problems to solve and so on... :-)